# Visual Studio 2015: The hash value is not correct

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

After installing Visual Studio Professional 2015 (using an RTM executable but selecting Update 2 during the setup process), I get the following warning:

[image: The hash value is not correct]

Everything *seems* to work fine, and all resources I can find online refer to [*errors* thrown by the installer of earlier versions of Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2014/05/01/incorrect-hash-value-when-installing-visual-studio-2013-update-2/). These, however, are only warnings.

Do I need to do anything or can I ignore them safely?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same "Hash value incorrect" error issue when i was trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise from a shared location. It got solved for me, when its installation started from from the local copy of the folder.

I.e. I have copied the setup files/packages into local drive and initiated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because my internet was restricted.  I had to download off-line copies of Visual Studio for SQL and SSDT.  The instructions below, however, are for **Visual Studio 2017**.

1. Download:  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=866452
2. `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout <folder name>`
3. Download:  https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_sql.exe
4. `vs_SQL.exe --layout <different folder name>` (this takes a while, it's laying out ~4 GB)
5. `<different folder name>\vs_setup.exe --wait --nickname "SSDT" --passive`
6. `<folder name>\SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe`

Notes:
For #2, yes it's "15" even though you're downloading Visual Studio 17.  I think it ha to do with Visual Studio 2017 being at version 15 and Visual Studio 2015 being at version 17.

References:

- [Visual Studio 2017 SSDT offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857178/visual-studio-2017-ssdt-offline-install)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c41001f-7d93-4318-96c7-75fa3c416605/offline-installer-for-ssdt-2017?forum=ssdt
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt