# Visual Studio 2017 SSDT offline install

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I require an offline install for **SSDT** for Visual Studio 2017.  Or how to hack the online download.  (note not VS itself I have that offline install).  I have used the online download to obtain the .vsix files but I need a way to install them.

- Double click doesn't work,
- Rename to .zip and extract and place them
  in the folder doesn't work.
- There is an ISO available but it's only
  for 2015

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 18):

You can download the offline layout using /layout input.

```
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout c:\vs2017ssdt
```

You can find out what parameters can be sent in, if you enter

```
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /?
```

Once you have the offline layout of ssdt installer, you can copy it to a machine that doesnt have internet access and install there.

Comment: Invoke the executable from the local folder (c:\vs2017ssdt)...it will take a while and then it will find the downloaded files and install them.  @Taavi: your post solved the issue.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

- [Visual Studio 2017 installation using offline installer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visual-studio-2017-installation-using-offline-installer/)
- [Download Visual Studio 2017 web installer isocommunity professional
  enterprise](https://developerinsider.co/download-visual-studio-2017-web-installer-iso-community-professional-enterprise/)
- [Install VS Inconsistent Quality Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

Open CMD on windows and run below command

**For .NET web and .NET desktop development, run:**

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

**For .NET desktop and Office development, run:**

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

**For C++ desktop development, run:**

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```

***To create a complete local layout with all features (this will take a long time—we have lots of features!), run:***

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --lang en-US
```